# Unable to scrape full data using r

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape information about 'google cloud platform free tier' from Stackoverflow but I am able to scrape only the first 15 comments and not the rest. Please note that I am able to scrape the full data from other Stackoverflow link.

```
site <- paste0('https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=google%20cloud%20platform%20free%20tier')

webpage <- read_html(site)

draft_table <- html_nodes(webpage,'.excerpt')

draft <- html_text(draft_table)

finaldf99<-data.frame(draft)

nrow(finaldf99)
```

Please help.

Thanks,
Tanuvi

Comment: why not just use the api? http://api.stackexchange.com/docs

Comment: @hrbrmstr..Thanks..